# HttpPostedFile.SaveAs error, rooted path?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

I have an HttpPostedFile object, when I try saving it via SaveAs I get this exception System.Web.HttpException

> The SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path, and the path './tempUpload/4' is not rooted.

Why? how do I correct it?

Answer (score 3):

The path should be an absolute path, not a relative url.

Use the `Server.MapPath` method to get the absolute path from your relative url.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET doesn't like the dot in your path. Try 'tempUpload/4' instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for saving a file.

```
string trailingPath = Path.GetFileName(fileName+".wav");
string fullPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Recordings"), trailingPath ?? throw new InvalidOperationException());
file.SaveAs(fullPath);
```