# How to give path of a folder in server to save an image?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, save-as, server.mappath

I'm trying to store an image into two applications (both published on server). This is my code to save the image :

```
 string path = Server.MapPath("/Images/Landing/bottom_banner/");           
 string path1 = @"_http://10.241.193.22/Myapplication/Images/Landing/bottom_banner/";
  HttpPostedFileBase photo = Request.Files["adup"];
            if (photo.ContentLength != 0)
            {
                string lastPart = photo.FileName.Split('\\').Last();
                Random random = new Random();
                int rno = random.Next(0, 1000);
                photo.SaveAs(path + rno + lastPart);
                photo.SaveAs(path1 + rno + lastPart);
            }
```

**Note: `Myapplication` is another application hosted on the same server**

My problem is I am able to save the image in my first application using `Server.MapPath` but when the compiler comes to the part  `photo.SaveAs(path1 + rno + lastPart)` it gives an error:

> The SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path, and the path '_http://10.241.193.22/Myapplication/Images/Landing/bottom_banner/676Chrysanthemum.jpg' is not rooted

Please suggest how can I eliminate this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089713/httppostedfile-saveas-error-rooted-path

Comment: in that question the person is trying to save the file in only one application.Here i am trying to save into two separate applications.

Comment: nevertheless there is a solution given in the first answer, try using it for your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether this is right but can you do this ?

In the current application store the Server.MapPath value and then replace the current application name with "Myapplication" and then add the trailing path. Something like this

```
string path1 = Server.MapPath("");
path1.Replace("Application1", "Myapplication"); //Considering "Application1" is the name of your current application
path1 += "/Images/Landing/bottom_banner/";
HttpPostedFileBase photo = Request.Files["adup"];
        if (photo.ContentLength != 0)
        {
            string lastPart = photo.FileName.Split('\\').Last();
            Random random = new Random();
            int rno = random.Next(0, 1000);
            photo.SaveAs(path1 + rno + lastPart);
        }
```

There might be a permission problem with this one. I have not checked it. If it works please let me know.

Comment: I will try this on monday and let you know though i think its the correct way to do it and it should work.Anyhow will let u know once i check

Answer (score 1):

You should POST image to the second server and use same method (Server.MapPath) there.

It's impossible to save image (or other file) at remote server.

if you know absolute paths (for example) 'C:\Web\ApplicationOne...\image.png\' and 'C:\Web\ApplicationTwo...\image.png' you can replace path difference like this:

```
photo.SaveAs(path + rno + lastPart);
photo.SaveAs(path.Replace("ApplicationOne", "ApplicationTwo") + rno + lastPart);
```

Comment: see OP: "Myapplication is another application hosted *on the same server*"

Comment: both the applications are on the same server